# How to make the column text appear to single line instead of multiple lines in datatable of shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, format, width, dt

This is how my day column in the datatable appears:

[image]

I removed some of the columns to adjust the day column to make it to appear in single row instead of two rows.
The date-column is now like this: '2022-' and in next line '11-24'. I want date column to be like this '2022-11-24'. How can I do this without using width parameter.

I tried all datatable parameters, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: zoom out on your browser, so the font size changes and appear in one line

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS `white-space: nowrap`:

```r
library(DT)
library(shiny)

dat <- mtcars
dat$test <- "2022-12-08"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      "
      td {
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
      "
    ))
  ),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dtable <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```